# Size of Android Screens with no status bar and softkeys

Tags: android, android-emulator

What is the applications screen size without the status bar and softkeys(in some phones)?

Like for Example i know:

320X480 trimmed down to 320X455 which is the basesize.

but what about others , i have done many calculations and a lot of searches online to figure out a defined size for other screen but i seems can't, Also While applying the formula *.75 ldpi, *1.5 hdpi, *2.25 xhdpi   to get other screen, it doesn't add up.

Like 320X480 is mdpi to get the hdpi do *1.5 and you will get 480X720 which is not the situation for devices out their ! and using this method my application images where stretched, this method is according to the Google documentation, i'm confused as hell.

I have tried to et sizes using the emulator also it was very different! for height.

So if the problem is with height only, i'm thinking creating background as patterns and then work only on the width of the screen size and re-size every other elements to screen width only like 240px, 320px, 480px, 720px and also consider the size of them to fit minimum height.

I believe it's not possible to define a height for android which will go like generic because of the variety of android devices.

So what do you think about this approach to use background as pattern and forget about every device on earth height ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use tile pattern, create a small texture and then make it tileable drawable in xml, so it will be tiled across screen, or the second might be using 9-patch images, in that way you can select which area of the image scale and which area to not scale, so they will be scaled according to that way.

Comment: I know about this way, but i will have to rethink many stuff in resources, so i was making sure if the pattern would be a nice idea. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: you're welcome :) also consider using 9-patch images, they're really useful